# How to implement a simple newsletter/subscription system and mask recipients list

Tags: php, email

I need to create a simple e-newsletter or subsciption system in PHP. At first, I thought of using PHPList for WordPress but the plugin is compatible only up to 2.9.2, if I recall correctly.

- how can I mask my recipients list?
- what must I consider to not have mails considered as spam?
- how to send mail in batches?

I am open to use of plugins or 3rd party frameworks. I think they would provide valuable insight to create such a system from scratch.

Comment: Too many questions at once. And nobody will write up a tutorial here. You should consider using a readymade script for that.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots and lots of services that can provide newsletter services for you.  You should seriously consider using one of them instead of rolling your own.  Consider [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/), [Exact Target](http://www.exacttarget.com/products/email.aspx) and [Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/email-marketing/index.jsp) as popular options.  All of them provide appropriate APIs.

Comment: yes I am considering that, but I just am curious how do these scripts do it? just for learning